# Java/Ant - Compile multiple variations

Tags: java, ant

I currently have a Java project in Netbeans 7.3, which contains a settings.java class. Within that class are 3 booleans that turn on/off various features of the program (eg: trial, full, etc).

Although it is one project in Netbeans, it actually produces 6 different versions of the program, which I currently have to manually create by editing the variables, compiling and copying, editing the variables, compiling and copying.... six times. This is rather time consuming and inefficient.

Is there a way for my to accomplish the 6 builds without manually editing->compiling six times?

Thanks!

----EDIT----

Thanks for the help! In case anybody has a similar question, I ended up writing a java class that modifies the settings file and compiles using ant.

My solution: https://gist.github.com/patopop007/5561428

Comment: Is there a java property that corresponds to each of the booleans you want to switch on?

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you mean by "java property" but they essentially dictate various functionality within the program. (eg: whether a dialog pops up or not, etc)

Comment: If you really need 6 different binaries, to restrict usage of the program ... in your ant build script, copy the source to a temp directory and then use sed, or equivalent, to modify the booleans in the temporary source files and then compile within the temp directory.  Move the output files to the relevant output directory.  Then repeat for the other combinations of booleans.

Comment: Properties/property files are one method commonly used to configure code at runtime.  [This coderanch thread](http://www.coderanch.com/t/471530/java/java/Read-boolean-property-file) has a simple example near the end of it. @jarmod 's method would work to create different binaries.  You could do something similar by making/jarring the six different versions of the Settings class one time.  Then you could control builds/runs by including the appropriate jar on the classpath.  If your computer can handle it you could make 6 projects with the same source but different output path dirs thay way.

Comment: Thank you both for your help! I ended up writing a java class which does what sed does and compiles using ant.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions come to mind:

1. Create several NetBeans project. One will be a library which contains all the code common between all the different builds. Then create a new NetBeans project for each of the separate builds.
2. Create different custom ant targets in your NetBeans file for each build. For example

   ```
   <target name="trial">
       <!-- Stuff specific to the trial build goes here. -->
   </target>

   <target name="full">
       <!-- Stuff specific to the full build goes here. -->
   </target>
   ```

   The specifics depend on the exact differences between the builds.